# Deleting secure search malware

Tags: virus, avg-antivirus

How do I delete secure search (AVG virus) malware?

I am using Firefox as my browser. I am able to bypass it when it appears on start up, but I cannot find and completely remove this irritation?

Answer (score 0):

I hate when this happens.
What you will need to do is look for an uninstall entry in the uninstall programs section. if there is none, check firefox's extensions. if the secure search item is in there, just uninstall it. If neither of those suggestions work, the secure search has probabbly been installed by third party software. check your recently installed programs to see if it was installed as an "offer" alongside the program.